# Traefik failing https redirection

Tags: https, docker-compose, next.js, traefik, http-redirect

I have a docker-compose using traefik 1.7 to act as a proxy for my website. My website server is Next.js. I cannot manage to perform http to https redirection while having the same configuration working on other of my applications.

Here is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '2'

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik:1.7
    restart: always
    command: |-
      --logLevel=DEBUG
      --web
      --entrypoints='Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https Redirect.Permanent:true'
      #--entrypoints='Name:http Address::80'
      --entrypoints='Name:https Address::443 TLS'
      --docker
      --acme
      --acme.entrypoint=https
      --acme.email=test@mail.com
      --acme.storage=/etc/traefik/acme.json
      --acme.ondemand=false
      --acme.onhostrule=true
      --acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=http
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik:/etc/traefik/
  website-preprod:
    image: registry/taggedimage
    restart: always
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=my-website"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:domainname.com"
      - "traefik.docker.network=root_default"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
      - "traefik.port=3000"
    environment:
      - HTTPS_CERT=server/certificates/dev.crt
      - HTTPS_KEY=server/certificates/dev.key
      - HTTP2=false
      - API_ENDPOINT=https://api.domainname.com/api
      - HTTPS=true
    depends_on:
      - proxy
    networks:
      - default
      - inner
networks:
  inner:
    driver: bridge
    internal: true
```

Https works, but the redirection from http to https does not.
Traefik logs seems ok, except that it does not redirect at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the comment `#--entrypoints='Name:http Address::80'` was the issue there. Since docker-compose is translated to a command line, this line was breaking the previous line of the redirection.